# Can someone explain the grammar in this sentence "もうこれで終わってもいい"

Tags: translation, て-form, particle-で, particle-も

I'm having problems with the particle で and its main function here. I can't figure out the real meaning of this sentence.

> もうこれで終{お}わってもいい

I found that [Verb + Te-form + もいい] is used to ask permission to do the action of the verb, which conflicts with the context of the scene (a firm, decisive affirmation) from this page of a manga:

[image]

Comment: I think verb-temoii is more "if verb it's okay". https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-flashcard-7/ So this is something like "Now, with this, it's okay to end". But that's rough since there is no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky without more context but, the whole passage seems like:

**"And now with this (something), (it doesn't matter if/I don't care if) it all ends now. So I'm gonna give it everything I've got..."**

The first bit **もうこれで** is pretty ambiguous.

Literally translated:

もうこれで - So with this...

終わってもいい - It's fine if this is the end.

だから - So...

ありったけを - Everything I've got...

It would be helpful if we could see the surrounding pages as well.

*Edit: Fixed a misreading with updated meaning.*

Comment: 「もうこれ**だ** 。」じゃなくて「もうこれ**で** 」ですけど。。（「もうこれで終わってもいい」で１文）

Comment: @Chocolateあら確かにそうですね。訂正ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Chocolateやっぱ素人目の私には難しすぎますかね。。。

Comment: えっ、難しいですか？いや、そんなに難しくないから大丈夫だと思いますけど。。

Answer (score -1):

The line sounds like, “It doesn’t matter even if I end (or die? if I correctly understand the context) now.”

ても sounds like “even if”.